# Why object method is rewrites the original objects?

Tags: javascript

Why when we rewrite the value of the method `foo` of the nested object `s` it's also rewrites the original object `z` method `foo`?

Explaine someone, please why it does and how to prevent it from rewrite?

```
const z = { foo: 'bar' };
const s = z;
s.foo = 'baz'; 
s == z // true
```

Comment: Because both `s` and `z` are referencing to the same object

Comment: @HassanImam thank you! But how we can prevent that from rewrite the original obj?

Comment: Try cloning the object using spread syntax or `Object.assign()`.

Comment: ... `const s = {...z};`